# create a very small filesystem 4k or smaller

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems

I'm trying to create a very small Linux filesystem. Something 4k or smaller.

It's for an experiment with backup software that does block level backups.

I've got a Linux logical volume that's 4K in size but using `mkfs.ext3` or `mkfs.ext4` I'm running into issues

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/smallvg/small_lv

mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
mkfs.ext3: inode_size (128) * inodes_count (0) too big for a
    filesystem with 0 blocks, specify higher inode_ratio (-i)
    or lower inode count (-N).
```

I'm also running into err

```
[root@anoop-cent6-2 ~]# mkfs.ext2 -b 1024 -i 1024 -I 128 -N 16 /dev/smallvg/small_lv 
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/smallvg/small_lv: Not enough space to build proposed filesystem while setting up superblock
```

Is there a way to create a very small filesystem? it need not be ext3 or ext4. I just need to mount it as something.

Comment: Gotta ask... Why?

Comment: It needs to be read/write?  Otherwise I would say cramfs

Comment: Perhaps the [CP/M](http://www.cpm8680.com/cpmtools/cpm.htm) FS? Or maybe the original FAT, if you can force its creation.

Comment: FAT 12/16/32 all have to much overhead.  The FAT table is 9kb on 1 floppy disk. No file system I know of supports 4k partition size.  Even a floppy disk was 360k/1440k.

Comment: If you want to test something with your backup software, which does block-level backup, you should probably see which file systems it even supports.

Comment: Why do you even need a filesystem?  Just write some data to the volume?

Comment: Maybe Petit FAT File and I stress maybe http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_p.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern filesystems typically allocate data in chunks of 4KiB. Thus, creating a whole filesystem that fits in that space is impossible -- it would be like trying to fit a 10-liter container inside a 1-liter space. For that matter, hard disks use 512-byte logical sectors, so 4KiB is just 8 sectors in size.

It's conceivable you could find some exotic or very old filesystem that would fit on such a small partition, but I'm skeptical of that. Even the floppy disks used with really ancient computers like Atari 8-bits were 90KiB or so in size.

As others have suggested in comments, if you're experimenting with block-level backup software, you may not even need a filesystem -- just write a data file directly to the partition and see how the software handles it. Alternatively, create a larger partition; with a modern disk, you should be able to read and write something on the order of 4MiB quite quickly.